# What is the cheapest and easiest way to install/run SAS on a Mac?

Tags: macos, sas

I am taking a lab course on SAS for Finance this semester and the professor is stating that the lab only has licenses for Windows.  We have not yet met for class and he has been unresponsive through e-mail.  Is there a way to install SAS on a Mac or does anyone have other suggestions?

Comment: It's unlikely that your professor arranged for these licences himself; try talking to your faculty and/or the SAS institute itself; you may be able to get an equivalent Linux license.

Answer (score 2):

Hard to beat free. See https://www.sas.com/en_us/software/university-edition.html

Runs on a mac in a virtual machine. Or skip the install and run it in AWS.

Answer (score 0):

Install a Windows VM on your Mac and use VMWare to run Windows and install SAS that way. I'm going to recommend you do this, because if you're taking Finance you'll likely need PROCS in the SAS/ETS package which are not included in SAS UE. VMWare can be purchased at a steep discount if you're a student, or you could get some help spinning up an AWS Windows Instance, install SAS there and run it off there. Expect to spend approximately $15-20 a month for something like that.

Another cloud option is SAS for Academics On Demand - you can choose the independent learner route - which is free and does have SAS/ETS.